# How to use JasperReports with Play Framework

Tags: jasper-reports, playframework

Im searching the web but still couldn't find any way to integrate JasperReports with the Play Framework. Have any of you did it before? If so please show me what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice example for using Jasper with Play:

https://gist.github.com/1143821

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's too generic of a question. Probably the easiest way is to use the [web services](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/WebServices) of Jasper via the WS library or Java libraries. In the [link](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mwiki/index.php/Jasperserver/WebServices) you have some Java code samples.